# Laravel переодическое удаление старых записей

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

В БД есть таблица нотификаций, из которой нужно раз в месяц удалять устаревшие записи.

Как организовать периодичность выполнения работы в Laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL имеет [встроенный планировщик](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html).

Для решения поставленной задачи следует его включить и создать периодическое задание на удаление устаревших записей.

Например, для ежедневного удаления записей старше года это будет

```sql
CREATE EVENT remove_old_records
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS CURRENT_DATE
DO
DELETE FROM `tablename`
WHERE `datetime` < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
```